# Assigning long to Long in Java

Tags: java, android, object, type-conversion, primitive

I am currently going through one of the [Android Tutorials](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html). I found an expression like:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
Long longVariable = bundle.getLong(someId);
if( longVariable != null )
{
  //doSomething
}
```

After looking at Bundle.getLong in the API I saw that it returns a *long* (primitive).
Now, I didn't write Java for quite a while, only C# in the meanwhile, but how can the object *Long longVariable* variable ever be null?

Comment: `long` != `Long`, the uppercase one is a wrapper class around the lower case primitive. See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html

Comment: I think he knows that. What he's asking is `long i = some value; Long j = i;` and then *immediately* checking if `j == null`

Comment: @alextsc: I know. Otherwise I wouldn't have asked :).

Comment: Just wanted to clearify that. Sounded like you dont know to me, because when you know that this is a class (which is used here), it should at least be clear how it can be `null`.

Comment: @alextsc it still isn't clear to me how **longVariable** can be null in this example.

Comment: Ok I didn't take this context too much into consideration, what I meant was that a Long can be null in general. But not in this case since getLong() always returns a long primitive. Sorry for beeing ambiguous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `getLong()` really has return type `long` it can't be, i.e. `l` will never be null. Probably the programmer didn't look up the return type, but inferred from the method name a `Long` would be returned.

Comment: Something I wouldn't expect out of an official android tutorial that a lot of users must have read. Nonetheless that's what I would have guessed also, but I thought maybe there is more to it.

Answer (score 2):

What if you pass in the wrong id? Then it is not found, but do you get null, or an exception is raised?
Documentation states that:

```
public long getLong (String key)
Returns the value associated with the given key, 
or 0L if no mapping of the desired type exists for the given key.  
Parameters

     key    a String
Returns
     a long value
```

So it never returns null, but 0L eventually. However, getLongArray returns null sometimes, so it might be a leftover from using getLongArray?

Comment: if return type is "long" how can it be null? That's EXACTLY my question.

Comment: It never can be null, at worst it's 0L. I edited my answer to add the documentation :D

Comment: Perhaps the programmer's intent was to check `if (l != 0)` then.

Comment: exactly. So the check for null will always return true. Means the example is somehow flawed. At first I thought there might be some implicit mapping for 0L to null when boxing. But I thought this would be very weird behavior. Thus this question.

Answer (score 1):

In Java `Long` is an object and like any object it can be null.
`long` is a primitive type and cannot be null.

From Java 1.5 on wards Java supports auto-boxing and unboxing meaninng that it's convert between the primitives and objects automatically.

If a method returns `long` then it's probably safe not checking for `null` even if you cast it to a `Long` however if a method returns `Long` object its a good idea to check for nulls.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating new instance.
`bundle.getLong(someId)` returns the primitive `long` type not `Long`.
`Long l = new Long(bundle.getLong(someId));`

And then check `if(l != null)`

Make sure you have extracted the right `long` from the `Bundle`. Try `Log`ging this `Long` object see if it is all right.

`Log.i("MY LONG: ", String.valueOf(l));`